# Two of eight items in a dropdownlist not working VB.NET. Why do they jump to index 0?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dropdownbox

I have eight items populating from my database. They each have different text and value properties.  I bind them on  `If Not Page.IsPostBack Then`.  The other items in the dropdownlist are working on `ddlType_SelectedIndexChanged`. However I have two items that when I select them, it goes to the `SelectedIndexChanged` method and it thinks the index is at 0, and the value/text is the first one. Then the page reloads with the first value selected. Can anyone give me any direction or advice on how to solve this problem (it seems like a bug)??

The two items not working are at index 1 and index 7. Whenever I select them, page reloads with index 0. I've tried changing the index of these two values but no matter where they are in the dropdown, they do not work.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList> 

Protected Sub Page_Load1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        PopulateDropDownFields(ddlType, Session("LOB"), "NENB")
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the method where I use GetFields method which is a call to a select stored procedure with the eight values:

```
Public Shared Sub PopulateDropDownFields(ByVal theList As DropDownList, ByVal LOB As String, ByVal FieldType As String, Optional ByVal UseDescription As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal IncludeAll As Boolean = False)
    theList.Items.Clear()

    For Each s As Fields In Fields.GetFields(FieldType, LOB)
        If UseDescription Then                
            theList.Items.Add(New ListItem(s.Key, s.Value & "|" & s.Length))
        Else
            theList.Items.Add(New ListItem(s.Value))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm trying to debug it in this method but whenever I select these two values, it goes to the first value at index 0. The other six values in the dropdown work.

```
Protected Sub ddlType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlType.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim str As String = ddlType.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim index As Integer = ddlType.SelectedIndex

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you able to provide the code/markup in question?

Comment: What does the rendered markup for the dropdown list look like?  If it works for 6 but not the other two, I would suspect that the data being bound is creating two or more items with the same value.

Comment: What do you mean rendered markup for dropdown? Like the values in the database table?  I can assure you that all items being added have different values.  If you want to see the data in the table, I can show you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Protected Sub ddlType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As
>   EventArgs) Handles ddlType.SelectedIndexChanged
>
> ```
> Dim str As String = Sender.SelectedItem.ToString()
> Dim index As Integer = Sender.SelectedIndex
> ```
>
> End Sub

Comment: Thanks for your help but still thinks it's at index 0 and first text.